# Create a positioned CSS3 cross browser card flip without flicker (z-index / perspective issue?)

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transitions

Current trying to get a simple cross-browser 3D CSS3 card flip effect working on my test site.

The result works just fine in Firefox but in WebKit one half of the image disappears in the turn and also flickers quite a bit.

I already checked the code against working examples on the web like

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/CardFlip/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007646-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Since I could not find difficulties there, I now suspect the z-index position of the background and perspective values of the card playing against each other – though I could not find out by now how they co-relate.

Here is the CSS I use:

'#t02panel' serves as the card with '#t2front' and '#t2back' being its two faces.

Hiding #t02back's backface as well (which logically should neither do harm, nor be required…) saved the appearance from flickering in Firefox but did no good with WebKit.

```
        #t02front   {   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    } 
        #t02back    {   -webkit-transform: rotateY (-180deg);   -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);   -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);     transform: rotateY(-180deg);    }        
        #t02front, #t02back {   position:absolute; z-index: 1; box-sizing: border-box; 
                                    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;   -o-backface-visibility: hidden;     backface-visibility: hidden;    }

        #topic02        #t02panel       {   -webkit-perspective: 600;                               -moz-perspective: 600;                              -o-perspective: 600;                            perspective: 600;
                                            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                                            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;                   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;                  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                                            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;               -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;                 -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;                 transition: transform 1s;
                                            -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;                    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;                   -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;                 transition: all 1.0s linear;    }
        #topic02:hover  #t02panel       {   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);                     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);                    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);                  transform: rotateY(180deg);     }
```

Any input on how getting this to work cross browser is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a WebKit bug. Here is a work around. You'll no longer see the flicker if you apply the following to the image that is revealed when the card flips:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px);
```

This pushes that image 1px backwards in the 3D space, creating enough of a separation between the front and back images. If you make it anymore than 1px, you can see the elements are separated, but 1px is enough not to make a difference.

You could apply `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);`to the front image but as you'll see, it causes the image to get a little bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Moving the "backside" image backwards on the Z does indeed help remove the flicker, but does not solve the original issue of half of the image completely disappearing behind the outer element's background during the turn.

Also learnt: WebKit (tested in Safari) does not like multiple arguments per transform-parameter.

Had to go with

```
    -webkit-transform:  rotateY (-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:  translateZ(-1px);
```

rather than

```
    -webkit-transform:  rotateY (-180deg) translateZ(-1px);
```

in order to create the desired result.

Comment: Where did you find that webkit does not like multiple arguments per transform parameter? You will be erasing the -webkit-transform property with the second declaration. You should combine multiple properties on the same line. You should be fine with -webkit-transform:  rotateY (-180deg) translateZ(-1px);